# Check if a Key is present in a nested array of Objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Below is a code example. I want to write a if(*condition*) that will check if the key 'chart' is present in the object *Obj* and return true or false.

I am not sure how to do it for an array

```js
var Obj = {
  carousel: {
    container: [{
      title: 'First slide 01',
      image: 'img 1',
      buttons: ['OK', 'Cancel', 'Submit', 'Send', 'Abort']
    }, {
      title: 'Second slide 02',
      chart: {},
      buttons: ['Alpha', 'Beta']
    }, {
      title: 'Third slide 03',
      video: 'video 1'
    }, {
      title: 'Fourth slide 04',
      audio: 'audio 1',
      buttons: ['link', 'embed']
    }]
  }
}
if('chart' in Obj){
 alert('true')
}
else {
 alert('false')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ES6 `filter` to do this.

```js
const
  Obj = {
    carousel: {
      container: [{
        title: 'First slide 01',
        image: 'img 1',
        buttons: ['OK', 'Cancel', 'Submit', 'Send', 'Abort']
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Second slide 02',
        chart: {},
        buttons: ['Alpha', 'Beta']
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Third slide 03',
        video: 'video 1'
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Fourth slide 04',
        audio: 'audio 1',
        buttons: ['link', 'embed']
      }]
    }
  };
  
function getChartContainers(containers) {
  // Filter returns an array with items from the source array that meet your
  // condition. In this case filter only includes the objects where chart is
  // not undefined.
  return containers.filter(item => item.chart !== undefined);
}

const 
  charts = getChartContainers(Obj.carousel.container);
  
if (charts.length === 0) {
  console.log('there are no charts');
} else {
  console.log(`there are ${charts.length} charts`);
}

console.log(charts);
```

## More generic

You could also make this more generic in case you want to filter on something else than `chart`.

```js
const
  Obj = {
    carousel: {
      container: [{
        title: 'First slide 01',
        image: 'img 1',
        buttons: ['OK', 'Cancel', 'Submit', 'Send', 'Abort']
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Second slide 02',
        chart: {},
        buttons: ['Alpha', 'Beta']
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Third slide 03',
        video: 'video 1'
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Fourth slide 04',
        audio: 'audio 1',
        buttons: ['link', 'embed']
      }]
    }
  };
  
function getContainersWithTypeOfContent(containers, contentType) {
  // Filter returns an array with items from the source array that meet your
  // condition. In this case filter only includes the objects where chart is
  // not undefined.
  return containers.filter(item => item[contentType] !== undefined);
}

const 
  charts = getContainersWithTypeOfContent(Obj.carousel.container, 'chart'),
  audio = getContainersWithTypeOfContent(Obj.carousel.container, 'audio');
  
if (charts.length === 0) {
  console.log('there are no charts');
} else {
  console.log(`there are ${charts.length} charts`);
}

if (audio.length === 0) {
  console.log('there is no audio');
} else {
  console.log(`there are ${audio.length} audio slides`);
}
```

## ES5 solution

In case you're not comfortable with ES6, you can also do this in ES5.

```js
var
  Obj = {
    carousel: {
      container: [{
        title: 'First slide 01',
        image: 'img 1',
        buttons: ['OK', 'Cancel', 'Submit', 'Send', 'Abort']
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Second slide 02',
        chart: {},
        buttons: ['Alpha', 'Beta']
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Third slide 03',
        video: 'video 1'
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Fourth slide 04',
        audio: 'audio 1',
        buttons: ['link', 'embed']
      }]
    }
  };

function getContainersWithTypeOfContent(containers, contentType) {
  var result = [];
  
  // Iterate over all the items in the containers array.
  for (var index = 0; index < containers.length; index++) {
    // Get the item at the current index.
    var currentItem = containers[index];
    // Check if the current item has the content type specified.
    if (currentItem[contentType] !== undefined) {
      // Push the item in the result array when it meets the content criteria.
      result.push(currentItem);
    }
  }
  
  // Return the array with items that match the specified content type.
  return result;
}

var 
  charts = getContainersWithTypeOfContent(Obj.carousel.container, 'chart'),
  audio = getContainersWithTypeOfContent(Obj.carousel.container, 'audio');

if (charts.length === 0) {
  console.log('there are no charts');
} else {
  console.log('there are ' + charts.length + ' charts');
}

if (audio.length === 0) {
  console.log('there is no audio');
} else {
  console.log('there are ' + audio.length + ' audio slides');
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, but requires transpiling to use it in browser.

Comment: It depends on your browser requirements... most browsers will handle it fine.

Comment: that's true, but it always will be the one funny guy who uses IE9.

Comment: For that one funny guy I've added an ES5 solution to my answer.

Comment: I see. I just really love lodash. It allows you to have small and readable code when you work with collections.

Comment: I agree but if you just want to do this, why add a whole library to your code base? Besides, while lodash is extremely useful, it is also good to know how to do these kind of things yourself.

Comment: It's hard to disagree, no reason to add library just for one validation.

Answer (score 0):

The laziest way to do that is to use lodash or underscore _.get and/or _.find function. Something like

```
var element = _.find(
   obj.carousel.container, 
   function(value) { return 'chart' in value; }
);
if (!!element) alert ('Here we are!');
```

Answer (score -1):

try this Obj.hasOwnProperty('chart');

```
if ( Obj.hasOwnProperty('chart') ) { alert('true'); }
else { alert('false'); }
```

check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) for documentation

Comment: Yes it is - I just assumed that he is looking for the immediate child key